# Django - Get Related Key and Insert into Database

Tags: python, django, models, foreign-key-relationship

Ok, so what I'm trying to do is allow the user to add a "product" to their shop but without having to choose the shop to add it to as each user will only have ONE shop.

I'm getting the:
"IntegrityError at /shop/product/add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: shop_product.business_id"

This is what's being shown in the local variables:
[Local Vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QolAv.jpg)

**Local Vars:**

```
Variable    Value
__class__   <class 'shop.views.ProductCreate'>
form    <AddProductForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(product_name;product_desc;product_image)>
s    <Shop: 4>
self     <shop.views.ProductCreate object at 0x048B0370>
user     10
```

Now I believe the issue might be the "s" variable's  as the code is actually getting the correct shop.. but it's also adding that weird "

My Code as it is right now.

**models.py**

```
 # Shop Model. A Shop Object will be created when the user registers
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="owner")
    shop_logo = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ": " + str(self.owner)

    def create_shop(sender, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs["instance"]
        if kwargs["created"]:
            up = Shop(owner=user)
            up.save()
    post_save.connect(create_shop, sender=User)

    def shoplogo_or_default(self, default_path='/static/images/dft/no-img.png'):
        if self.shop_logo:
            return self.shop_logo
        return default_path


    # The class that will link a product to the shop
class Product(models.Model):
            product_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
            # connect the product to the shop
            business = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products")
            product_desc = models.TextField()
            product_image = models.FileField()

            def __str__(self):
                return self.product_name
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = AddProductForm
    template_name = 'shop/add-product.html'

        def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(commit=False)
        # get current logged in user
        user = self.request.user.id
        # match the current logged in user to an owner in the Shop model
        s = Shop.objects.get(owner=user)
        #  get the id of that owner's shop identification number
        form.business = str(s.id)
        form.save()
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        return super(ProductCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

The above should in theory get the current logged in user, match that user to a shop within the shop model as an owner and then get that shop ID.

**forms.py**

```
class AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['product_name', 'product_desc', 'product_image']
    exclude = ['business']
```

I'm rather new to Django and a student so I'd like to apologise if you see anything weird.

Thank you :)

Comment: Ah! I'll fix that in just a mo. Thank you for informing me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but don't try to edit the shop value into the form. Instead, capture the in-memory `Product` instance from saving the form and assign its `business` attribute:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    new_product = form.save(commit=False)
    # get current logged in user
    user = self.request.user.id
    # match the current logged in user to an owner in the Shop model
    s = Shop.objects.get(owner=user)
    # assign the shop instance to the product
    new_product.business = s
    # record the product to the database
    new_product.save()
    # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
    # It should return an HttpResponse.
    return super(ProductCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Oh wow! that worked! Thank you ever so much for the help! So when working with relational data (for lack of a better word), I would need to capture the model instance that I want to create, and then save or do whatever I need with that?

Comment: I'll mark your response as the answer as soon as I can. Really appreciate the help you've given me :)

Comment: If the relation isn't determined from the form, yeah. This is a pretty common pattern if, say, you want to record the user who created each record.

Comment: Perfect!! I think I understand what you mean now with the non-form determined relationship. Wish I'd known that earlier. Cheers for that! (y)

Comment: The point there is that you can have form fields to choose related objects - say, a dropdown to select from a predefined set of categories or something like that. If all your relationships are of that type you can just save the form without `commit=False`.  But you usually don't want to do that for relationships that depend on the user or other request attributes, as in this case.

Comment: Ah. Dropdowns being populated from other models. Something that I feel I need to look into sooner or later as I progress. I think I'll be able to populate a dropdown through a ModelChoiceField and getting a list of objects. Bahh! I think I'll leave it for today. Thank you so very much for walking me through this. You're an absolute star!